# solving a tridiagonal power matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

I am trying to solve a tridiagonal matrix power in R, as shown below. This a tridiagonal matrix at the power of 't'. It can be interpreted as a classic transition matrix in a Markov chain.

The paper that I'm reading (https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0040580915001124) suggests to use the Al-Hassan, 2012 method to solve this matrix power with an exact solution.

```
        1-migr migr/2 0      0      migr/2
        migr/2 1-migr migr/2 0      0     
  M =   0      migr/2 1-migr migr/2 0     
        0      0      migr/2 1-migr migr/2
        migr/2 0      0      migr/2 1-migr

Pk(t) = Pk * (M^t)
```

Do you know of any implementation of this algorithm in R, or can you suggest me how I could implement it?